# stm32f1 RTC Alarm

Tags: microcontroller, stm32f1

I'm using stm32f103RBT6 and I want to set RTC alarm event every one hour by using codes below

```
RTC_Alarm_Time.Alarm = 1;
HAL_RTC_GetTime(&hrtc,&RTC_Time,RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours=RTC_Time.Hours+1;
if(RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours>23)
{                                           
    RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours=0;   
}   
RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Minutes=RTC_Time.Minutes;                       
RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Seconds=RTC_Time.Seconds;  
HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT(&hrtc, &RTC_Alarm_Time, RTC_FORMAT_BIN);
```

my problem is after hour 23 alarm comes at hour 1 and it skips hour 0.
I think its because when i set alarm hour to 0 RTC date is still previous day.
does anyone has any example of codes that i can make this Independent of date or any other way.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer:**

There is a bug in your code.  Your code sets `RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours=RTC_Time.Hours+1`, and then checks for the hour rollover with `if(RTC_Time.Hours>23)`.  Note that `RTC_Time.Hours` was not incremented, rather `RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours` was incremented.  So when `RTC_Time.Hours == 23`, `RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours = 24`, and `RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours` will not be rolled over to 0 because `RTC_Time.Hours` is not greater than 23.  Then the call to `HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT()` will fail because `Hours` = 24.  You would have caught this if you were checking the return value of `HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT()`.

You can fix your code by changing the conditional like this.

```
if(RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours>23)
```

**Original Answer (would address the suspected problem on a STM32F4):**

I think you're right about it skipping hour 0 because the date is the previous day.  You should ignore the date/day because you want an hourly alarm.  And I think you can ignore the date/day by setting `RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmMask = RTC_ALARMMASK_DATEWEEKDAY`.  This should mask (i.e., ignore) the date/day so that the alarm will occur based upon only the hour, minute, and second.

Comment: I tried it but gives an error that AlarmMask is not a member of RTC_AlarmTypeDef.I'm using  "stm32f1xx_hal.h" library that includes stm32f1xx_hal_rtc.c lib.does this library has other commands to ignore date?or can i just set rtc alarm by a counter?

Comment: Ah, sorry the STM32F1 does not support the `AlarmMask`.  I was looking at STM32F4 documentation.  But it looks like the STM32F1 RTC hardware does not know the date/day and the date is always ignored for the alarm.  (The STM32F1 RTC is a simple counter and the HAL implementation limits alarm detection to 1 day ).  The conversion from date/day to count happens in the STM32F1 HAL, in  `HAL_RTC_SetAlarm()`.

Comment: @tariq  I have updated the answer with the actual solution.  The problem is not what we suspected.

Comment: @ kkrambo sorry i made a mistake type code in my question here. my code was 
if(RTC_Alarm_Time.AlarmTime.Hours>23) in my main program and i still have this problem.The problem does not come from anywhere else?in my main code i want to wakeup from stop mode every one hour can i just set alarm  by a counter?or any other way?Thankyou.

Comment: @tariq  I don't see anything else wrong.  Check the return value of `HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT()`.  Then step through the code in the debugger to see where is misbehaves.  Step into `HAL_RTC_SetAlarm_IT()` and watch how it handles the case where the alarm hour is less than the current hour.